# Inconsistent Scaling in SwiftUI Projects

Tags: ios, user-interface, swiftui, layout, ios-simulator

I recently copied my SwiftUI code from one Xcode project into a new project. The code in both projects is currently identical, and I'm running both projects on the same simulator, but the scaling within the simulator is different. This leads me to believe that I might be missing some difference within the project settings, but I'm not sure what it could be.

Here's the code as a minimal reproducible example:

```
struct MyApp: App {
        
    var body: some Scene {
        
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 40)
            .foregroundColor(.red)
            .frame(width: 400, height: 400)

    }
}
```

Here is the screenshot from the old project:
[Image from old project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHWM6.png)

And here is the screenshot from the new project:
[Image from new project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdYCW.png)

Notice that the old project red square is larger than the new project red square, though the code is the same. What could be causing this?

Same files within different projects run on the same simulator should produce the same result.

- Searched through targets settings.
- Cleaned build settings
- Deleted derived data
- Restarted Xcode

Comment: what's the minimum deployment for the older project? Also, nice catch.

Comment: On a second thought, I really have doubts if it has anything with the minimum deployment target because you're hardcoding the values

Comment: on a third thought, I think the minimum deployment target is the key here, nativeScale and scale properties of the Scene can change depending on your SwiftUI and iOS version.

Comment: I also had some issues recently with the simulators showing larger text. Check Settings > Developer > Display Zoom.

Comment: @grandsirr Great question... It's a multi target app with iOS at 16.0 and macOS at 12.3, in both projects.

Comment: @grandsirr I think you are getting very close... I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and multi-target apps, and don't understand the intended behavior around scaling. In my original project, my app looks pretty much the same regardless of what iPad I choose. In my new project, larger iPads make my graphics look tiny. It seems like my old project is scaling content and my new project is using absolute values. I'd like the old scenario, but don't know how to replicate the settings.  https://www.dropbox.com/sh/j86l0lw2jh0co4g/AABGKneYMALrRtywSIgnihg1a?dl=0